# Is there a way to do a non-blocking Dispose()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dispose, idisposable

I have a project which after some time can have thousands of controls on it, and each of those controls are being disposed cleanly, however this process is starting to take up a lot of processor time and it locks the UI when calling Dispose on the parent object.

Is there anyway to do a cascade dispose of all objects and sub objects inside a container without blocking the UI in the process ?

To replicate the problem, you can create a new Control, with a sub Control, and each of those sub controls, add another control to them. After this, make sure you have proper Dispose() code in each control and sub control, then use this loop in the parent Dispose() method:

```
while(Controls.Count > 0) { Controls[0].Dispose(); }
```

Then drop this new control with multiple sub controls (I use a custom Add method to add all the sub controls to the parent).

Once you have a hundred or so of these controls visible in the new control container, call it's dispose method ---  the absolute parent of your custom control.  A simple structure would be as follows (not including their sub Dispose methods)

```
public class MyCoolClass : ScrollableContainer, IDisposable {

    public List<MyBox> Boxes { get; set; }

    public MyCoolClass() {
        Boxes = new List<MyBox>();
    }

    public Add() {
        MyBox box = new MyBox();
        int next_top = 0;
        if(Boxes.Count > 0) {
            next_top = Boxes[Boxes.Count-1].Top + Boxes[Boxes.Count-1].Height + 10;
        } else {
            next_top = 10;
        }
        box.Top = next_top;
        Boxes.Add(box);
        Controls.Add(box);
    }

    public ReloadBoxes() {
        Controls.Clear();
        SuspendUpdate();
        int next_top = 0;
        foreach(MyBox box in Boxes) {
             if(next_top==0) { next_top = 10; }
             box.Top = next_top;
             next_top = box.Top + box.Height + 10;
        }
        ResumeUpdate();
    }

    internal class MyBox : Control, IDisposable {
           internal class WriteArea : RichTextBox, IDisposable {

           }

           WriteArea TT;

           public MyBox() {
                TT = new WriteArea();
           }
    }

}
```

Comment: You say you can have thousands of these controls in a container at a time.  Is this because these are all useful controls?  Or is it because even as some controls are no longer useful, you keep accumulating them?

Comment: Simplest solution - don't create so many controls. Use data binding, UI virtualization and partial loading to only load and display the data that is actually visible. Grids for example don't load millions of rows in memory nor do they create thousands of edit boxes. You can only modify controls from the UI thread which means you can't run the disposal in the background.

Comment: Why do you need so many controls? What are they doing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - An example of so many controls would be a chat window with bubble messages, etc.

Comment: I was considering using the .DisposeAll() for the array of objects, however I have no clue as to the parameters it is asking.  It definitely should be much faster that a `while` loop.  Perhaps if someone gave an example of that, it could give the performance boost necessary to not really worry about whether the Disposes are blocking or not. -- Just a thought.   Also Panagiotis -- the elements are being managed like that as I had to much about with the spacing etc when using them in a ScrollableContainer as they were dorking up. Watched resource usage and it stays the same no matter the count.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the controls to a separate collection, clear the controls from the form and then spin off a background worker to handle the dispose.

```
List<Control> OldControls = new List<Control>(MyForm.Controls);
MyForm.Controls.Clear();
// Create background worker to dispose of the controls in OldControls
```

[Backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Controls can only be modified by the UI thread. Have you tried what you posted?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.  No I didn't try it or I would have included the BackgroundWorker code too.  But once I Clear them from the form are they still controls or just a collection of objects that need to be disposed? My thought was they are not longer bound to the UI so they could be disposed.

Comment: A control can only be modified by the thread that created it. That's what people mean when they are talking about the UI thread. Removing a control from a form doesn't change the fact that it was created in a specific thread. Disposing actually releases the GDI objects that were created on that thread. Check [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,3e1c4673cebe4b6d) to see that Dispose is doing a lot of UI work

Comment: Panagiotis is correct.  You 'could' do it on a BackGround thread object, however you would have to `.Invoke()` for each iteration which would result in the same problem of the UI thread being blocked, plus it is dangerous if the instance has more than one UI thread (rare,  but happens).